# Function Return an Associative Array

Tags: chapel

How can you have a function return an associative array in Chapel? This is what's natural, but doesn't seem to work:

```
type keys = domain(int);
type arr = [keys] int;

proc factor(q): arr {
...
}
```

The error output I get is:

```
error: unresolved call 'chpl__ensureDomainExpr(type DefaultAssociativeDom(int(64),true))'
$CHPL_HOME/modules/internal/ChapelArray.chpl:642: note: candidates are: chpl__ensureDomainExpr(const ref x: domain)
$CHPL_HOME/modules/internal/ChapelArray.chpl:649: note:                 chpl__ensureDomainExpr(x ...)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a working program that does this:

```
proc returnsAssocArray() {
  var AssocDom:domain(int);
  var AssocArray:[AssocDom] int;
  AssocArray[1] = 100;
  return AssocArray;
}

var A = returnsAssocArray();
for (key,value) in zip(A.domain, A) {
  writeln("A[", key, "] = ", value);
}
```

The above is the pattern that I would use and probably does what you want.

Note that arrays and domains in Chapel have a *runtime* relationship, and that the type of an array includes the *runtime* domain. So while the code you posted might one day work, generally speaking to specify an array type one needs to specify a domain that is available at runtime.

Supposing you wished to share a single domain (aka set of keys) among all of the associative arrays returned, you could do this:

```
var AssocDom:domain(int);
AssocDom += 1; // add index 1 to the associative domain
type AssocArrayType = [AssocDom] int;

proc returnsAssocArray(): AssocArrayType {
  var AssocArray:AssocArrayType;
  AssocArray[1] = 100;
  return AssocArray;
}

var A = returnsAssocArray();
for (key,value) in zip(A.domain, A) {
  writeln("A[", key, "] = ", value);
}
```

But, if `returnsAssocArray` wanted to add `2` to the domain (say), things might not work as you expect:

- adding `2` to AssocDom will resize any other arrays created over that domain
- just doing `AssocArray[2] = 100` will add to the domain only if there are no other arrays sharing that domain.

It's likely that future versions of Chapel will have a `Map` type to simplify such use cases and present a more familiar interface for maps. Additionally, the rule about adding to the associative domain if no other arrays share it may well go away.